# Trouble interpolating column name for subset in R function

Tags: r, subset, user-defined-functions, sapply

I have `(fbodata) 'data.frame': 6181090 obs. of  41 variables:`

I want to subset it and save the portion that pertains to a specific subset (like a zip). My approach seems to work when it is not in a function, but I ultimately want to use sapply.

```
    nmakedir <- function(item, ccol) {
  snipped a bunch of code that works
    trim<- fbodata[ which(paste(ccol)==item),]
    trim%>% drop_na(paste(ccol))
    trim<- droplevels(trim
    save(trim, file = paste(item, "rda", sep="."))
        }
```

The line that doesn't work is one where I creating the subset with which. If i hardcode the line using `fbodata$zip` instead of `paste(ccol)` it works fine. Eventually, I plan to call it with something like:

```
sapply(unique(fbodata$zip),zip, FUN = nmakedir)
```

I appreciate any clues, I have been on this for a good long while.

Comment: it is disheartening the need to downvote the question because you felt the format needed improvement.

Comment: It's hard to know who downvoted and their reason (since they didn't comment). My assumption for the downvote is because of no sample data shared, but who knows.

Comment: it was because I didn't properly block quote my code correctly maybe because I haven't participated enough, it is not because I didn't care. I think they removed their downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things going on:

- `ccol` is a string. `paste(ccol)` is the same string. You never need to call `paste` with only one argument. (You can use `paste` to coerce non-strings to strings, but in that case you should use `as.character()` to be clear.)
- Keeping in mind that `ccol` is a string, what is `fbodata$zip`? It's a column! What is the equivalent using `ccol` and brackets? `fbodata[[ccol]]` or `fbodata[, ccol]`. You can use either of those interchangeably with `fbodata$zip`. So, this bad line

  ```
   fbodata[ which(paste(ccol)==item),]
   # should be this:
   fbodata[which(fbodata[[ccol]] == item), ]
  ```
- `drop_na`, like most `dplyr` functions, expects (quoting from the help) "*bare variable names*", not strings. Also from the help, "*See Also: `drop_na_` for a version that uses regular evaluation and is suitable for programming with*". In this case, I don't think you need to do anything more than replace `drop_na` with `drop_na_`.
- You are missing a right parenthesis on your `droplevels` command.

There might be more, but this is much as I can see without any sample data. Your `sapply` call looks funny to me because I thought `zip` is supposed to be a column name, but when you call `sapply(unique(fbodata$zip),zip, FUN = nmakedir)` it needs to be an object in your global environment. I would think `sapply(unique(fbodata$zip), 'zip', FUN = nmakedir)` makes more sense, but without a reproducile example there's no way to know.

It also seems like you're coding your own version of `split`. I would probably start this off with `fbo_split = split(fbodata, fbodata$zip)` and then use `lapply` to `drop_na_`, `droplevels`, and `save`, but maybe your snipped code makes that a less good idea.

Comment: thank you very much, i understand what you said and appreciate you wading through my confused approach.